# How to find cdf of beta distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

How would you go about integrating:

$ C\int_{-\infty}^{x}x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}dx$ where C is the beta function. Would I have to employ integration by parts or employ a numerical method?

$u = x^{a-1}$

$du = (a-1)*x^{(a-2)}dx$

$dv = (1-x)^{b-1}dx$

$v = 1/(b-2)*(1-x)^{b-2}$

The integral is:

$x^{a-1}*1/(b-2)*(1-x)^{b-2} - \int 1/(b-2)*(1-x)^{b-2}(a-1)*x^{(a-2)}$

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

The pdf the Beta distribution is defined as $\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)} $. Note that the support is $[0,1]$. So the cdf is $$P(X \leq t) = \int_{0}^{t} \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \ dt$$

Comment: But to evaluate the integral do you use integration by parts?

Comment: There is no closed form for the integral I guess.

Comment: The (regularized) incomplete beta function is the "closed form" solution: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html